# Only one usage of each socket address - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (SQL: select * from`users`where`id`= 1 limit 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i am also facing this issue 
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (SQL: select * from users where id= 1 limit 1)
Issue i faced  in laravel`